# Gstreamer multicast RTP : Unexpected discontinuity in audio

Tags: gstreamer, multicast, rtp, beagleboneblack

I get errors when i run Gstreamer audio multicast RTP on a [BeagleBone Black](https://beagleboard.org/black).

Here is the Gstreamer **TX** command:

```
# gst-launch-1.0 -v filesrc location="test.wav" ! decodebin ! audioconvert ! rtpL16pay ! queue ! udpsink host=224.0.0.10 auto-multicast=true port=5555 --gst-debug-level=3
```

> Setting pipeline to PAUSED ... Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
>   /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstTypeFindElement:typefind.GstPad:src:
>   caps = audio/x-wav
>   /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstTypeFindElement:typefind.GstPad:src:
>   caps = NULL 0:00:00.300210292 23288    0x75490 FIXME
>   default
>   gstutils.c:3648:gst_pad_create_stream_id_printf_valist:
>   Creating random stream-id, consider implementing a deterministic way
>   of creating a stream-id
>   /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstWavParse:wavparse0.GstPad:src:
>   caps = audio/x-raw, format=(string)S16LE, layout=(string)interleaved,
>   channels=(int)2, channel-mask=(bitmask)0x0000000000000003,
>   rate=(int)48000
>   /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstAudioConvert:audioconvert0.GstPad:src: caps
>   = audio/x-raw, layout=(string)interleaved, rate=(int)48000, format=(string)S16BE, channels=(int)2,
>   channel-mask=(bitmask)0x0000000000000003
>   /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpL16Pay:rtpl16pay0.GstPad:src: caps =
>   application/x-rtp, media=(string)audio, clock-rate=(int)48000,
>   encoding-name=(string)L16, encoding-params=(string)2, channels=(int)2,
>   payload=(int)96, ssrc=(uint)3613934853,
>   timestamp-offset=(uint)2678744220, seqnum-offset=(uint)28780
>   /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstQueue:queue0.GstPad:src: caps =
>   application/x-rtp, media=(string)audio, clock-rate=(int)48000,
>   encoding-name=(string)L16, encoding-params=(string)2, channels=(int)2,
>   payload=(int)96, ssrc=(uint)3613934853,
>   timestamp-offset=(uint)2678744220, seqnum-offset=(uint)28780
>   /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstUDPSink:udpsink0.GstPad:sink: caps =
>   application/x-rtp, media=(string)audio, clock-rate=(int)48000,
>   encoding-name=(string)L16, encoding-params=(string)2, channels=(int)2,
>   payload=(int)96, ssrc=(uint)3613934853,
>   timestamp-offset=(uint)2678744220, seqnum-offset=(uint)28780
>   /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstQueue:queue0.GstPad:sink: caps =
>   application/x-rtp, media=(string)audio, clock-rate=(int)48000,
>   encoding-name=(string)L16, encoding-params=(string)2, channels=(int)2,
>   payload=(int)96, ssrc=(uint)3613934853,
>   timestamp-offset=(uint)2678744220, seqnum-offset=(uint)28780
>   /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpL16Pay:rtpl16pay0.GstPad:sink: caps =
>   audio/x-raw, layout=(string)interleaved, rate=(int)48000,
>   format=(string)S16BE, channels=(int)2,
>   channel-mask=(bitmask)0x0000000000000003
>   /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstAudioConvert:audioconvert0.GstPad:sink: caps
>   = audio/x-raw, format=(string)S16LE, layout=(string)interleaved, channels=(int)2, channel-mask=(bitmask)0x0000000000000003,
>   rate=(int)48000
>   /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0.GstDecodePad:src_0.GstProxyPad:proxypad1:
>   caps = audio/x-raw, format=(string)S16LE, layout=(string)interleaved,
>   channels=(int)2, channel-mask=(bitmask)0x0000000000000003,
>   rate=(int)48000 /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpL16Pay:rtpl16pay0:
>   timestamp = 2678744220 /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpL16Pay:rtpl16pay0:
>   seqnum = 28780 Pipeline is PREROLLED ... Setting pipeline to PLAYING
>   ... New clock: GstSystemClock

And the Gstreamer **RX** command:

```
# gst-launch-1.0 -v udpsrc multicast-group=224.0.0.10 auto-multicast=true port=5555 caps='application/x-rtp, media=(string)audio, clock-rate=(int)48000, encoding-name=(string)L16, encoding-params=(string)2, channels=(int)2, payload=(int)96' ! rtpL16depay ! audioconvert ! alsasink --gst-debug-level=3
```

> Setting pipeline to PAUSED ... Pipeline is live and does not need
>   PREROLL ... Setting pipeline to PLAYING ... New clock: GstSystemClock
>   /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstUDPSrc:udpsrc0.GstPad:src: caps =
>   application/x-rtp, media=(string)audio, clock-rate=(int)48000,
>   encoding-name=(string)L16, encoding-params=(string)2, channels=(int)2,
>   payload=(int)96
>   /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpL16Depay:rtpl16depay0.GstPad:src: caps =
>   audio/x-raw, format=(string)S16BE, layout=(string)interleaved,
>   rate=(int)48000, channels=(int)2,
>   channel-mask=(bitmask)0x0000000000000003 0:00:00.357371500 23249
>   0xefb20 WARN                    alsa conf.c:4694:snd_config_expand:
>   alsalib error: Unknown parameters {AES0 0x02 AES1 0x82 AES2 0x00 AES3
>   0x02} 0:00:00.358214833 23249    0xefb20 WARN                    alsa
>   pcm.c:2239:snd_pcm_open_noupdate: alsalib error: Unknown PCM
>   default:{AES0 0x02 AES1 0x82 AES2 0x00 AES3 0x02}
>   /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstAudioConvert:audioconvert0.GstPad:src: caps
>   = audio/x-raw, layout=(string)interleaved, rate=(int)48000, format=(string)S16LE, channels=(int)2,
>   channel-mask=(bitmask)0x0000000000000003
>   /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstAlsaSink:alsasink0.GstPad:sink: caps =
>   audio/x-raw, layout=(string)interleaved, rate=(int)48000,
>   format=(string)S16LE, channels=(int)2,
>   channel-mask=(bitmask)0x0000000000000003
>   /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstAudioConvert:audioconvert0.GstPad:sink: caps
>   = audio/x-raw, format=(string)S16BE, layout=(string)interleaved, rate=(int)48000, channels=(int)2,
>   channel-mask=(bitmask)0x0000000000000003
>   /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpL16Depay:rtpl16depay0.GstPad:sink: caps =
>   application/x-rtp, media=(string)audio, clock-rate=(int)48000,
>   encoding-name=(string)L16, encoding-params=(string)2, channels=(int)2,
>   payload=(int)96 0:00:08.472125917 23249    0xefb20 WARN
>   audiobasesink
>   gstaudiobasesink.c:1593:gst_audio_base_sink_get_alignment:
>   Unexpected discontinuity in audio timestamps of +0:00:00.010583333,
>   resyncing 0:00:51.970270047 23249    0xefb20 WARN
>   audiobasesink
>   gstaudiobasesink.c:1593:gst_audio_base_sink_get_alignment:
>   Unexpected discontinuity in audio timestamps of +0:00:00.002729166,
>   resyncing 0:00:51.982288589 23249    0xefb20 WARN
>   audiobasesink
>   gstaudiobasesink.c:1593:gst_audio_base_sink_get_alignment:
>   Unexpected discontinuity in audio timestamps of +0:00:00.010437500,
>   resyncing 0:00:52.010382256 23249    0xefb20 WARN
>   audiobasesink
>   gstaudiobasesink.c:1593:gst_audio_base_sink_get_alignment:
>   Unexpected discontinuity in audio timestamps of +0:00:00.006937500,
>   resyncing 0:00:52.029231922 23249    0xefb20 WARN
>   audiobasesink
>   gstaudiobasesink.c:1593:gst_audio_base_sink_get_alignment:
>   Unexpected discontinuity in audio timestamps of +0:00:00.007354166,
>   resyncing

As you can see above, warnings are printed to the console and audio is cracking and noisy :

*audiobasesink gstaudiobasesink.c:1593:gst_audio_base_sink_get_alignment: Unexpected discontinuity in audio timestamps of +x:xx:xx.xxxxxxxxx, resyncing*

Any idea to solve this issue ?

Thank you for reading.

Note that both Gstreamer commands run on the same machine. it acts like a local audio loopback actually.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want an `rtpjitterbuffer` on the receiver side. UDP does not guarantee the order of packets when they arrive and this element will take care of it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Florian
I forgot to say that both Gstreamer commands run on the same machine. it acts as a local audio loopback actually.
Do you think UDP packets could be disordered ?

Comment: @Ludovic sure, it's not guaranteed.

Comment: I have placed a `rtpjitterbuffer` right after the `udpsrc` and I got the same traces, so that doesn't solve the problem for me. Any more advice?